# UTC conversions work in development but not in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, heroku, timezone

On my development machine, all is well. The event_date gets stored as UTC and converted as it should, in and out of active record. However, in production on heroku, rails stores the date without converting it to UTC, and then when it is fetched, it is converted to the user's timezone, which essentially creates an inaccuracy because the offset isn't being applied to a UTC time.

I'm using Postgres both locally and on Heroku.

```
Parameters: {"name"=>"asdfdsafdas", "date"=>"12/19/2013", "time"=>"10:00 PM", "location"=>"asdfdsfds", "description"=>"", "team_id"=>"1", "event"=>{"team_id"=>"1", "description"=>"", "location"=>"asdfdsfds", "name"=>"asdfdsafdas"}}

def create
  d = DateTime.strptime(params[:date], '%m/%d/%Y')
  t = Time.zone.parse(params[:time])
  event_date = Chronic.parse(params[:date] + " at " + params[:time])
  params[:event][:event_date] = event_date
  params[:event][:user_id] = current_user.id
  @event = Event.new
  if @event.update_attributes params[:event]
    render "events/show"
  else
    respond_with @event
  end
end
```

The event_date variable looks like this:

```
2013-12-19 20:25:00 -0500
```

**Edit:**

I found this [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/6816) on github that appears to be the closest thing to what I'm experiencing. It actually seems to be identical. However, it's closed, but I believe it should be open.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the problem had to do with how I was building the custom Time object. Here is the code that worked:

```
def create
  d = Date.strptime(params[:date], '%m/%d/%Y')
  t = Time.zone.parse(params[:time])
  event_date = t.change(day: d.day, month: d.month, year: d.year)
  params[:event][:event_date] = event_date
  params[:event][:user_id] = current_user.id
  @event = Event.new
  if @event.update_attributes params[:event]
    render "events/show"
  else
    respond_with @event
  end
end
```

In this case the event_date variable looked like this:

```
Wed, 18 Dec 2013 22:00:00 EST -05:00
```

Comment: Just expanding the answer to those with the same issue. 
I was getting the DateTime from a datepicker. It's better to use `Time.zone.parse` than trying with `DateTime.strptime`. After that, it can saved directly without any issue.